# Chutes and ladder simulation

Tags: r, histogram, simulation, estimation

I am begginer in R and trying to simulate chute and ladder game. Now I want to find or estimate the average position or moves reached by single player after the 10th turn and also simulate multiple times to get the variance and plot histogram. Reffered below codes. Please guide me.

```
max_turns <- 10  # number of turns to take
position <- 0  # start on the board
max_position <- 100 # number of box on board
n_sides_die <- 6 # number of sides on one die roll

                            
for (turn in 1:max_turns){      # use a for loop to simulate a number of turns
  die_roll <- sample.int(n_sides_die, 1) # simulate the values from rolls of an unbiased six-sided die
  position <- position + die_roll # compute new board position
  if ( position >= max_position ){  # break out of loop if we roll die that is greater than or equal to 60
    break
  }
}

**EXPECTING OUTPUT TO BE SOMETHING LIKE THIS**

turn_               ladder
                     or
num start roll land chute end

1     0   1    1    chute 38
2    38   4   42    NA    42
3    42   1   43    NA    43
4    43   2   45    NA    45
5    45   5   50    NA    50
6    50   3   53    NA    53
7    53   6   59    NA    59
8    59   2   61    NA    61
9    61   3   64    ladder60
10   60   3   63    NA    63
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is via a transition matrix (`P` in my code below).  If you set up a matrix of probabilities that links the current square to the next square, then you just need to raise that matrix to the 10th power to find the distribution after the 10th turn.

```
## Start and end positions of the snakes and ladders
ladders.df <- data.frame(start=c(1,4,9,21,28,36,51,71,80), 
                         end=c(38,14,31,42,84,44,67,91,100)) 
chutes.df <- data.frame(start=c(98,95,93,87,64,62,56,49,47,16), 
                        end=c(78,75,73,24,60,19,53,11,26,6)) 
# We only need a vector of start squares and a vector of end squares
to <- c(chutes.df$end, ladders.df$end)
from <- c(chutes.df$start, ladders.df$start)


# This function takes the square you land on then applies:
# the reflection if more than 100
# the snakes and ladders
position <- function(x){
  if(x>100) x=100-(x-100)
  if(x %in% from) x <- to[which(from==x)]
  x
}




# Now set up the transition matrix. The probability of each dice roll number is 1/6

# Initialise a zero matrix
# I'm adding a position 101 which will be the starting 'zero' position.
P = matrix(0,nrow=101,ncol=101)
# Add 1/6 probability to every possible transition
for(i in 1:99){
  for(j in 1:6){
    P[i,position(i+j)]=P[i,position(i+j)]+1/6
  }
} 
# 100 is an absorbing state
P[100,100]=1
# Setting the rules for the first turn
for(j in 1:6) P[101,position(j)] <- P[101,position(j)]+1/6

# Distribution of positions after 1 turn from square 0 
# (row 101 are the positions starting from square 0):

P[101,]

# Distribution of positions after 2 turns from square 1:

(P %*% P)[101,]

# Distribution of positions after 10 turns from square 1 (with plot):

P2 <- P
for(i in 1:20) P2 <- P2 %*% P

P2[101,] |> plot(type="o")
```

[image]

Now suppose you wanted to simulate a path of 10 turns.

Use the fact that the position on the 10th turn has a multinomial distribution with probabilities given by `P[x,]` where `x` is the position on the 9th turn (etc).

```
# Start at square 0
pos <- 101

# Turn 1 comes from a multinomial distribution with probabilities P[pos[101],]
pos[2] <- which(rmultinom(1,1,prob = P[pos[1],] )==1)

# We can add more turns (say 10)

# Start at square 0 (matrix row 101)
pos <- 101
for(i in 2:11){
  pos[i] <- which(rmultinom(1,1,prob = P[pos[i-1],] )==1)
}

# Look at the path (without the starting 0):
pos[-1]

 [1]  2 14 20 42 43 45 67 69 70 74
```

Finally, to plot a histogram of the position reached after ten turns:

```
# 1 turn transition matrix
P2 <- P
# Add 9 more turns to get the 10 turn transition matrix
for(i in 1:9) P2 <- P2 %*% P

# Sample 10000 times from the distribution starting from 0 after 10 turns:
sims <- sample(1:100,10000,TRUE,prob = P2[101,1:100])

# Plot histogram
hist(sims, breaks=100)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, I highly appreciate it.  As you mentioned above add other snakes and a ladder - this is the commands I used to create board and snakes and ladder as below-

Comment: board <-rbind
  
  sort(91:100, decreasing=TRUE), 
  81:90,
  sort(71:80, decreasing=TRUE),
  61:70,
  sort(51:60, decreasing=TRUE),
  41:50,
  sort(31:40, decreasing=TRUE),
  21:30,
  sort(11:20, decreasing=TRUE),
  1:10 ) 
ladder.df <- data.frame(start=c(1,4,9,21,28,36,51,71,80), 
                        end=c(38,14,31,42,84,44,67,91,100))
chutes.df <- data.frame(start=c(98,95,93,87,64,62,56,49,47,16),
                        end=c(78,75,73,24,60,19,53,11,26,6))
so in such case how I will show snake n ladder as x in position <- function(x)

Comment: I've added the code to do that and fixed a couple of other things.  In particular I forgot you start off the board (square 0).  R can't have a 0 index so I added a new state called 101 to represet the starting 0 square.

Comment: Thank you @georgesavva. I was trying to plot a histogram (mandatory*) instead of a graph from the given command but is m getting errors. Can you please guide me?

Comment: A histogram of what?

Comment: Plot a histogram of the position reached after 10 turns.

Comment: You could do this by using `replicate` on the code I gave you to simulate one path, or by sampling from 1:100 using the transition matrix as weights.  I've added the code to do the latter.

Comment: Thank you so much (infinite times), I highly appreciate your selfless help and guidance. Thank you once again histogram plotted perfectly, and I am so relieved, Thanks a lot.